# Why does my car lose velocity when racing in GTA-Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Sometimes I'm racing and my car loses a little velocity. Why is that happening, could it be a internet lag issue? The other thing that happens a lot is that for example I'm in the 1st position during a long straight route, and the car in the 2nd position reaches me. We both have the exact same vehicle (no custom allowed), and I'm going max speed, how come he can reach me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called Catch-up.  It's a race setting that speeds up the players in back and slows down players in front.  It can be enabled/disabled by the host in the lobby.

Also players close behind you can slipstream for a temporary speed boost.

Comment: I can confirm this.   Beat me to it @CaulynDarr :P

Comment: Basically, it's: "*We like people who can't play; those who can should be punished*". I hate it when games do that. In singleplayer mode, it's known as "*Rubber Band AI*".

Comment: @Nolonar Well I sometimes like to keep it on to either deter dirty racing or to encourage it (depending on your view of it) lol

Comment: @Nolonar In some cases I agree with you, but not with this game. This is GTA5, not GT5. Without catch-up, whoever escapes the first pileup gets ahead and gets to play by themselves for a few minutes and win with no challenge. Where's the chaos and destruction in that? Even if I'm out in front I'd much rather have people catch up to me and duke it out than just do a few laps all by myself! But I guess that's why they included it as an option, so we both can be happy :)